# add custom widget to DataGrid in GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I am trying to add a custom widget in a DataGrid cell in GWT.
The widget has 2 anchors and I want to be able to choose the action to take depending on the anchor clicked.
is there any example on how to do this.
My widget renders but it is unable to handle the clicks events.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cell Widgets, you have to use cells. It's a different way of thinking, building the UI and handling events, though.